# How to invoke a SOA Webservice operation (method) in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

Unfortunately, there aren't many examples on how to invoke a SOAP webservice. The example in the documentation is very vague, especially for new learners.

This is the scenario.
I have a webservice which has many operations.
In the xml configuration, I have a transformer which extracts information from message's payload and stores the data in a POJO. For now, the transformer is constructing the soap request with data from POJO. At the end, the transformer is returning and placing in requestChannel a message which is just the soap request as string.

I am invoking the webservice as it is in the example in docs; something like this.

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="invokeService"
                 request-channel="requestChannel"
                 reply-channel="responseChannel"
                 uri="http://[host]:[port]/app/service" />
```

I am getting this error: **SoapFaultClientException: Unknown method**

I would like to know how I can invoke the soap webservice operation passing the POJO data to the soap request. The webservice operation (or method) has string parameters.

Also looking for a good tutorial or book on Spring Integration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Integration WebServices support is nothing more than messaging channel adapter implementations on top of Spring WS. So, if you have some doubts how to build and receive SOAP messages, please, consult with that project: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/. You probably need to provide a SOAP Action header: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ws.html#ws-message-headers.

Also see respective sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/basic/ws-outbound-gateway.

With existing POJO you may consider to use a `Marshaller` approach. The JAXB is a good one to have annotations and generation based on WSDL.